# How to add custom UserDetails class with Spring Security and Keycloak OAuth2/OIDC

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

I'm using SpringBoot with `org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:6.0.1` and am currently accessing the user details like "family_name" via

```
String familyName = ((KeycloakAuthenticationToken)auth).account.keycloakSecurityContext.idToken.familyName
String employeeId = ((KeycloakAuthenticationToken)auth).account.keycloakSecurityContext.idToken.otherClaims["employeeId"]
```

Now I'd like to have a CustomUser class so that I can access all the attributes (OIDC as well as some custom claims) a bit more elegant via

```
 CustomUser u = ((CustomUser) auth).details
 String employeeId = u.employeeId
```

Where should I put the mapping to `CustomUser`? The `UserDetailsMapper` class does not play a role here, or? Should it be done in `AuthenticationProvider.authenticate()` by setting `authentication.details = <some subclass of KeycloakAccount>`?

Comment: Hello, do you find a solution for this ? Thanks :)

Comment: No, I switched to Spring OAuth2 client ("spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client") anyway.

Comment: Anyone has found a solution to this ever? Thanks